# Starting data on a freshly bought storage drive?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, data-transfer

I just bought a 480 GB SSD drive, and started by cloning my old HDD drive's content over. However, a lot of the sectors were unreadable and so I ended up aborting it. To get rid of this half-written data that was written onto my new SSD, I did a complete 00 write. Since I'm still kind of new to the whole hardware side of computers, I'm not sure if that was a good idea or not. Was there possibly data written on the SSD when I bought it that was needed or helpful for the operation of the drive? Or was it just all 00 like it is now? Thanks for the help and information.

Comment: The SSD contained no data, just duplicate the drive again, or install an OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that some data did exist, this would vary by manufacturer, but any data that could have existed would not have been necessary.  Just reformat the thing and carry on.  Also, there is no need to write zeroes over the whole thing unless you are trying to wipe data or remove some filesystem fingerprint, etc.